# Creating R function with local variable using its value

Tags: r, function

I would like to create a function that uses a variable already defined such that when I change this variable, the functionality of the created function doesn't change. Normally, when you use create a function in an environment using a variable defined in that said environment, the function will look up the value of the variable in that environment whenever it is called. For example:

```
> x = 3
> f = function() x + 3
> f()
[1] 6
> x = 4
> f()
[1] 7
```

I would like to create `f` such that it is simply the function `3 + 3` and always returns 6. Is there any easy way to do this in R? I know that I could manually assign the relevant parts of the function, i.e.

```
> body(f)[[2]] = x
> f
function () 
4 + 3
```

This strategy is quite tedious though, as it requires you to manually go through and change all occurrences. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Define `x` inside the function as well.  Right now `f` has to go outside the local scope to find `x`.  Or use a named argument `f <- function(x = 3) x + 3`

Answer (score 3):

Copy the value to a local variable:

```
f = local({
    x = x
    function () x + 3
})

f()
# [1] 6
x = 4
f()
# [1] 3
```

Now `f` is defined inside its own environment that contains the cached value of x:

```
ls(environment(f))
# [1] "x"
environment(f)$x
# [1] 3
```

Comment: Nice one.  I always forget about `local()`